# Read data from Qlikview into sas

Tags: sas

I have a qlikview data file.

The file includes:

- An XML formatted table header, after loading XML table header in sas system, I received some sasdatasets that describe about structure of qlikview data file, I made empty sasdataset that correspond with structure of qlickview data file.
- The actual data like that: " à@ à@ à@ @ ÁZ¦EÀ ÁZ¦EÀÁZ¦EÀ ", but I don't know what is format data is stored in?

Now I need load actual data into this empty sasdataset, but I don't know how can I do. My leader suggested using ''READING BYNARY DATA". I tried read by using statement INFILE and INPUT with ENCODING, but my implements aren't successful because very hard determine Binary Informat.

Can somebody give me suggestion ? thank so much!

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far along with any information you can find about the structure of the data.

Comment: Have you tried libname XMLv2?